# Data-driven graphs with Adobe Illustrator and XML/database

Tags: scripting, automation, adobe-illustrator, scene7

I'm trying to create an automated process where I could populate an illustrator file that includes bar charts and pie charts with variables, and then export PDF for each record I have in an XML file or database.

Adobe Help makes reference to using SVG and Graphics Server, but it looks like Graphics Server was EOL in 2008, and that I should look at Scene7, which is not suitable for the simple process I'm trying to do.

How should I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2):

The script VariableImporter.jsx allows you to import record sets which can include file path references to .csv or .txt formatted data spreadsheets so that a record can have the regular text, image, and linked-image variables as well as graph states. The extra step in the graph variable import is actually putting each graph state into a separate text file, after which point the script would refer to them via a file path just like a linked image, except it will parse the text spreadsheet into graph data.
https://github.com/Silly-V/Adobe-Illustrator/blob/master/Variable%20Importer/VariableImporter.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Well I found one way of doing the task...

http://www.vectorials.com/tutorials/Adobe-Illustrator-and-Data-Driven-Graphics-09196.html

I'm sure there are more ways of doing the same thing, so if you have another method to skin this cat, post away. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been on the hunt for similar.  The two that have come up in my search is Chartwell Font.  Where you physically type 25+50+25 and it makes a circle, bar, or radar chart.  Colors detonated by coloring of the numbers.
Or using the Variables tab in illustrator and then automating the each graph with the data used.  You would just need to import the graphs once the batch process was complete.

I was on the hunt as I generate 20-40 graphs for my proposals and not having to do that would save me time and allow me to get more done faster.  Good luck on your search!